# NetworkManager ignoring conf files at startup but not when restarted

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager

After booting, I have to restart the NetworkManager of Ubuntu 16.04 in order for it to work. I wonder why and how can I avoid it.

I have done the following changes:

1. On the GUI, for the Ethernet wired connection I'm using, under the `IPv4 Settings` tab, I have selected as Method `Automatic (DHCP) addresses only` and have no entry in `DNS servers`.
2. I have added a file at `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/unbound.conf` with the content:

   ```
   server=127.0.0.1#5553
   ```

   as I'm running an alternative DNS server under that port, which is working fine.
3. Analog to `unbound.conf` described above, I have two more conf-files in order to use alternative DNS servers for `.lxc` and `.lxd` domains, e.g. for `.lxd`:

   ```
   server=/lxd/10.0.8.1
   ```

This is the log generated when booting:

```
-- Logs begin at Mo 2018-04-09 08:38:52 CEST, end at Mo 2018-04-09 08:44:12 CEST. --
Apr 09 08:39:11 mac systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Apr 09 08:39:14 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255954.7053] NetworkManager (version 1.2.6) is starting...
Apr 09 08:39:14 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255954.7057] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
Apr 09 08:39:14 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255954.7082] manager[0x156c1c0]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Apr 09 08:39:14 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255954.7082] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Apr 09 08:39:14 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255954.7092] dns-mgr[0x154b960]: init: dns=dnsmasq, rc-manager=resolvconf, plugin=dnsmasq
Apr 09 08:39:14 mac systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6890] init!
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6891]       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6891]       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6891] management mode: unmanaged
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6894] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0f0, iface: enp3s0f0)
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6894] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0f0, iface: enp3s0f0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6894] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6894] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6894] end _init.
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6894] settings: loaded plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list. (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so)
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6895] settings: loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2015 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6896] SettingsPlugin-Ofono: init!
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6896] SettingsPlugin-Ofono: file doesn't exist: /var/lib/ofono
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6896] SettingsPlugin-Ofono: end _init.
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6897] settings: loaded plugin ofono: (C) 2013-2016 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list. (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-settings-plugin-ofono.so)
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6897] (22586272) ... get_connections.
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6897] (22586272) ... get_connections (managed=false): return empty list.
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6995] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1 (c1d67827-c587-3f04-a3c5-d4a3949bb857,"Wired connection 1")
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6999] SettingsPlugin-Ofono: (22586496) ... get_connections.
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6999] SettingsPlugin-Ofono: (22586496) connections count: 0
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7000] get unmanaged devices count: 0
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7009] settings: hostname: using hostnamed
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7009] settings: hostname changed from (none) to "mac"
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7010] Using DHCP client 'dhclient'
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7010] manager: WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7010] manager: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7010] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7011] Loaded device plugin: NMVxlanFactory (internal)
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7011] Loaded device plugin: NMVlanFactory (internal)
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7011] Loaded device plugin: NMVethFactory (internal)
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7011] Loaded device plugin: NMTunFactory (internal)
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7011] Loaded device plugin: NMMacvlanFactory (internal)
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7012] Loaded device plugin: NMIPTunnelFactory (internal)
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7012] Loaded device plugin: NMInfinibandFactory (internal)
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7012] Loaded device plugin: NMEthernetFactory (internal)
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7012] Loaded device plugin: NMBridgeFactory (internal)
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7012] Loaded device plugin: NMBondFactory (internal)
Apr 09 08:39:17 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255957.7377] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Apr 09 08:39:17 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255957.7516] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.1506] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.5409] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.5420] manager: (enp3s0f0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0)
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.5429] device (enp3s0f0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]: nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8203] device (lo): link connected
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8207] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8217] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lxdbr0, iface: lxdbr0)
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8218] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lxdbr0, iface: lxdbr0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8236] manager: (lxdbr0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8248] keyfile: add connection in-memory (3b2e54f3-86af-444a-809f-0bf5acccdd07,"lxdbr0")
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8253] device (lxdbr0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed') [10 20 41]
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8255] device (lxdbr0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed') [20 30 41]
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8263] device (lxdbr0): Activation: starting connection 'lxdbr0' (3b2e54f3-86af-444a-809f-0bf5acccdd07)
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8269] urfkill disappeared from the bus
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8276] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8283] device (lxdbr0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8290] ofono is now available
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8291] device (lxdbr0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8296] ModemManager available in the bus
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8299] failed to enumerate oFono devices: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8300] device (lxdbr0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8319] device (lxdbr0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8327] device (lxdbr0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8331] device (lxdbr0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8334] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 09 08:39:19 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255959.2378] device (lxdbr0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 09 08:39:19 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255959.2432] keyfile: add connection in-memory (17ff4ea2-2096-4935-8dfe-2bab6920d200,"G4 Network")
Apr 09 08:39:19 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255959.2442] bluez: BT device G4 (F8:95:C7:57:29:15) added (NAP)
Apr 09 08:39:19 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255959.2446] manager: (F8:95:C7:57:29:15): new Bluetooth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Apr 09 08:39:19 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255959.2456] device (F8:95:C7:57:29:15): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Apr 09 08:39:19 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255959.2464] keyfile: add connection in-memory (f98a835c-4fea-4cc9-a925-5410a00a80b8,"Moto G Play Network")
Apr 09 08:39:19 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255959.2472] bluez: BT device Moto G Play (CC:61:E5:13:BF:CD) added (NAP)
Apr 09 08:39:19 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255959.2478] manager: (CC:61:E5:13:BF:CD): new Bluetooth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Apr 09 08:39:19 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255959.2479] device (CC:61:E5:13:BF:CD): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Apr 09 08:39:19 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255959.2489] device (F8:95:C7:57:29:15): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none') [20 30 0]
Apr 09 08:39:19 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255959.2490] device (CC:61:E5:13:BF:CD): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none') [20 30 0]
Apr 09 08:39:22 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255962.2736] device (enp3s0f0): link connected
Apr 09 08:39:22 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255962.2739] device (enp3s0f0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
Apr 09 08:39:22 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255962.2744] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'
Apr 09 08:39:22 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255962.2753] device (enp3s0f0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (c1d67827-c587-3f04-a3c5-d4a3949bb857)
Apr 09 08:39:22 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255962.2754] device (enp3s0f0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 09 08:39:22 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255962.2755] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Apr 09 08:39:22 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255962.2758] device (enp3s0f0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 09 08:39:22 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255962.2760] device (enp3s0f0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 09 08:39:22 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255962.2766] dhcp4 (enp3s0f0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.0179] dhcp4 (enp3s0f0): dhclient started with pid 2339
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac dhclient[2339]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.104 on enp3s0f0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x15c74cfc)
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac dhclient[2339]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.104 from 192.168.1.1
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.4486]   address 192.168.1.104
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.4487]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.4487]   gateway 192.168.1.1
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.4487]   server identifier 192.168.1.1
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.4487]   lease time 604800
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.4487]   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.4487]   domain name 'localdomain'
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.4487] dhcp4 (enp3s0f0): state changed unknown -> bound
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.4496] device (enp3s0f0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.4500] device (enp3s0f0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.4519] device (enp3s0f0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.4520] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.6970] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.6971] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp3s0f0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255963.6972] device (enp3s0f0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 09 08:39:23 mac dhclient[2339]: bound to 192.168.1.104 -- renewal in 261032 seconds.
Apr 09 08:39:25 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255965.2731] manager: WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Apr 09 08:39:25 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255965.2732] manager: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.2743] manager: startup complete
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.3002] manager: (lxcbr0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.3220] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lxcbr0, iface: lxcbr0)
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.3220] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lxcbr0, iface: lxcbr0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.3225] device (lxcbr0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed') [10 20 41]
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.3243] keyfile: add connection in-memory (65a79898-22d6-44c6-ae69-3878829ad24b,"lxcbr0")
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.3249] device (lxcbr0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed') [20 30 41]
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.3256] device (lxcbr0): Activation: starting connection 'lxcbr0' (65a79898-22d6-44c6-ae69-3878829ad24b)
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.3264] device (lxcbr0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.3267] device (lxcbr0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.3269] device (lxcbr0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.3287] device (lxcbr0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.3291] device (lxcbr0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.3292] device (lxcbr0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 09 08:39:27 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255967.3299] device (lxcbr0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 09 08:39:33 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255973.2823] device (veth459KC7): failed to find device 5 'veth459KC7' with udev
Apr 09 08:39:33 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255973.2832] manager: (veth459KC7): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
Apr 09 08:39:33 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255973.2834] device (vethVVDRTP): failed to find device 6 'vethVVDRTP' with udev
Apr 09 08:39:33 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255973.2841] manager: (vethVVDRTP): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/7)
Apr 09 08:39:33 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255973.2919] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethVVDRTP, iface: vethVVDRTP)
Apr 09 08:39:33 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255973.2920] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethVVDRTP, iface: vethVVDRTP): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 09 08:39:33 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255973.2945] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth459KC7, iface: veth459KC7)
Apr 09 08:39:33 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255973.2945] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth459KC7, iface: veth459KC7): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 09 08:39:33 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255973.3121] device (veth459KC7): driver 'veth' does not support carrier detection.
Apr 09 08:39:33 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255973.3154] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth459KC7, iface: veth459KC7)
Apr 09 08:39:33 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255973.3284] device (vethVVDRTP): link connected
Apr 09 08:39:33 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255973.3285] device (lxdbr0): link connected
```

After restarting with `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` all work as expected, and these 3 lines appear, but are missing in the startup process:

```
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac dnsmasq[6419]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#5553
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac dnsmasq[6419]: using nameserver 10.0.8.1#53 for domain lxd                            
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac dnsmasq[6419]: using nameserver 10.0.3.1#53 for domain lxc
```

Unfortunately, I cannot post the whole restarting log due to a limitation of 30.000 characters here. An except of it follows:

```
-- Logs begin at Mo 2018-04-09 08:38:52 CEST, end at Mo 2018-04-09 08:45:09 CEST. --
Apr 09 08:39:11 mac systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Apr 09 08:39:14 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255954.7053] NetworkManager (version 1.2.6) is starting...
Apr 09 08:39:14 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255954.7057] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
Apr 09 08:39:14 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255954.7082] manager[0x156c1c0]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Apr 09 08:39:14 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255954.7082] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Apr 09 08:39:14 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255954.7092] dns-mgr[0x154b960]: init: dns=dnsmasq, rc-manager=resolvconf, plugin=dnsmasq
Apr 09 08:39:14 mac systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6890] init!
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6891]       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
...
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6894] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0f0, iface: enp3s0f0)
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6894] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0f0, iface: enp3s0f0): no ifupdown configuration found.
...
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6995] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1 (c1d67827-c587-3f04-a3c5-d4a3949bb857,"Wired connection 1")
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6999] SettingsPlugin-Ofono: (22586496) ... get_connections.
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.6999] SettingsPlugin-Ofono: (22586496) connections count: 0
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7000] get unmanaged devices count: 0
Apr 09 08:39:16 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255956.7009] settings: hostname: using hostnamed
...
Apr 09 08:39:18 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255958.8334] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 09 08:39:19 mac NetworkManager[1558]:   [1523255959.2378] device (lxdbr0): Activation: successful, device activated.
...
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.2344] device (lxcbr0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.2347] device (lxdbr0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.2350] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.2679] manager: startup complete
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.2683] device (enp3s0f0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.2689] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp3s0f0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.2708] dnsmasq[0x234e500]: dnsmasq appeared as :1.98
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac dnsmasq[6419]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac dnsmasq[6419]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#5553
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac dnsmasq[6419]: using nameserver 10.0.8.1#53 for domain lxd
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac dnsmasq[6419]: using nameserver 10.0.3.1#53 for domain lxc
...
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac dhclient[6498]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.104 on enp3s0f0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x78a1c5c6)
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac dhclient[6498]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.104 from 192.168.1.1
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.3991]   address 192.168.1.104
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.3991]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.3991]   gateway 192.168.1.1
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.3991]   server identifier 192.168.1.1
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.3992]   lease time 604800
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.3992]   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.3992]   domain name 'localdomain'
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.3993] dhcp4 (enp3s0f0): state changed unknown -> bound
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.4006] device (enp3s0f0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.4011] device (enp3s0f0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.4015] device (enp3s0f0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.4017] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256300.4027] device (enp3s0f0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 09 08:45:00 mac dhclient[6498]: bound to 192.168.1.104 -- renewal in 229782 seconds.
Apr 09 08:45:10 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256310.2733] manager: WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Apr 09 08:45:10 mac NetworkManager[6379]:   [1523256310.2734] manager: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
```

As a workarround, the NetworkManager can be restarted after startup automatically adding this line to `/etc/rc.local` (before the line `exit 0`):

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```